# Why didn't Lt. Kellaway thank Stanley Ipkiss at the end of The Mask?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-mask

At the end of the 1994 Comedy Film "The Mask" starring Jim Carrey, why didn't Lt. Kellaway (Peter Riegert) thank Stanley Ipkiss for saving everyone's lives in the Casino when Mayor Tilton (Ivory Ocean) deemed Stanley a Hero? Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 4):

Kellaway still thinks that Ipkiss was the original Mask (which he was) as well as a general menace to society (which he is). He's also not too thrilled about having been threatened at gunpoint.

He's clearly been told to **keep his mouth shut** by his superiors, but he's not happy about it. Note his *resignation* to what's happening.

> **STANLEY:** *Back to jail, Lieutenant?*
>
> **LT. KELLAWAY:** *Ipkiss, I'd like to lock you up for the rest of my life. But the mayor and a hundred other witnesses say Dorian Tyrel's the bad guy and you're the good guy. So no jail. Just a downtown parade at noon.*
>
> (RESIGNED)
>
> *And I've got to be your escort.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Mask - Original Screenplay](http://www.actorpoint.com/movie-scripts/scripts/the-mask.html)</sup></sub>